# Vuejs with arrays

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource

Im converting a JSON response to an array with the following:

```
        json_data = response.body.movies;
        var result = [];
        for(var i in json_data) result.push([i, json_data [i]]);
        self.movies = _.chunk(result, 3);
```

## Before I try to convert it, it's an object, looking like this:

[image]

## After converting:

[image]

I have to convert because lodash [chunk](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#chunk) method only works on arrays (?).

So when running `_.chunk(JSONAPIREPSONSE,4)`, `self.movies` looks like:

[image]

So far too good.

But when I'm trying to `v-for` `self.movies`, I cannot get the information i need. Im having this template

```
           <div class="row" v-for="(movie, index) in movies" v-bind:index="index">
                <div class="col-sm-4" v-for="(set, key) in movie" v-bind:key="key">
                    <div class="panel">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <a v-on:click.prevent="fetchNow(movie.movie_title)" :href="movie.movie_id">@{{ set.movie_title }}</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        movie title: <b>@{{ set.movie_title }}</b> <br>
                        set: <b>@{{ set }}</b> <br>
                              //Here comes Content do whatever here
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

And the result for `{{ set.movie_title }}` is empty, with no errors.

The result for `{{ set }}` is:

```
[ "0", { "movie_title": "Bridget Jones's", "movie_id": "17523" } ] 
[ "1", { "movie_title": "Strange", "movie_id": "17483" } ]
```

## The expected result

Normal vuejs syntax to display the content of the array.

Comment: It would help if you could include more of your Vue component (like the methods, data, and where the `_.chunk` call is being made).  Also, what is the structure of the `movies` object before converting it?  And what version of Vue is this -- 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: @PatrickSteele I have tried to update my answer. The method is just fetching data from a AJAX request, and is populated as the first image shown in my updated answer. `_.cunk` is a method from lodash. Its vue 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to access it like that `{{ set[1].movie_title }}`

and you can use `_.chunk` without convert the json response to array and access the result like that `{{ set.movie_title }}`